# 504 error in downloading large files from AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have different doc and pdf files that are stored in s3 bucket. I am downloading these files in zip format from s3 but if size of zip increase from 50MB it will give 504 error.

Comment: Please check for permissions in AWS. If possible, please share the bucket policy (remove any confidential information).

Comment: Yes granting permission solve my problem..
thanks

Comment: Please add an answer with some details so that future visitors can get a hint.

Comment: Hi which permission is that?